# How to make modifier for authorization of nested mapping addresses

Tags: solidity, mapping

May I know, how to make modifier for authorization of nested mapping addresses...

```
Mapping(address => mapping(address => uint) public allowance;

require(msg.sender == allowance[]); // Here we must give index...
```

But I want to authorize all addresses in this nested mapping... not only one specific address

Appreciate your quick response.

Comment: To do that it is required to iterate the mapping. With just a mapping it is not possible, but you can combine a mapping with an array to store the iteration keys. Usually iterating a large array is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to traverse all address, may use a map from address to an array, but this costs a lot of gas. If you only want to tell whether the address already exists, maybe use another map to maintain this kind of information.